# Why sample is placed after the interferometer in FTIR?

Tags: spectroscopy, interferometry

In all image of schematics of FTIR I found (Wikipedia for example), the sample is placed after the interferometer:

[image]

Wouldn't this miss some emergent effects, such photo-induced absorption, since the light coming out of the interferometer is missing some wavelengths due to interference ?

Consider a hypothetical system with first two excited states at 2eV and 3eV. When measuring absorbance with 620nm (2eV) and 1240nm (1eV) light, if both wavelengths are measured at the same time, it would show absorbance at both wavelengths due to ground state excitation 0->2ev and photo-induced absorption 2ev->3ev. However if they are measured separately, it would only show absorbance at 620nm because the ground state wouldn't absorb 1240nm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photo-induced absorption is an example of non-linear optical phenomenon: the response of the medium to two simultaneously present harmonic waves is not simply a sum of responses this medium would have to those waves if present individually. When both are present, one wave interacts, via the material medium, with another and a completely different state of medium and its behaviour is obtained.

This phenomenon is not considered to be present in ordinary absorption or reflection spectra, which is the main use of FTIR, either because it simplifies the analysis of the experiment (even if not entirely true), or due to the fact that the light wave is known to be not strong enough to make this phenomenon substantial.

In the first approximation, optical media usually behave linearly, i.e. different harmonic waves do not interact with each other. This is, of course, an idealization that is sometimes true, sometimes not. Especially if the waves are strong and close to allowed transitions in the medium, the idealization may cease to be valid.